# TV Series [1990s?] About a soldier lost in Amazon - Becomes super body guard

Tags: story-identification, tv

Not a lot to go on, but...

I remember watching a tv series in the 90's about a soldier who was lost/mia in the amazon(?). When he finally returned to civilization, he uses the things he learned in the jungle (from a tribe he lived with?) to be a super body guard or other "do-gooder".... not super powers, but heightened hearing, better eyesight, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It must be *The Sentinel* (1996-1999).

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sentinel_(TV_series)) page:

> Jim Ellison was a US Army Ranger who spent 18 months in the Peruvian jungle after the rest of his unit was killed. He developed hyperacute senses from surviving in the wild, but repressed them when he returned to civilization. His sensory abilities re-manifested five years later, while conducting an extended stakeout in the forest as a detective in the Major Crimes Unit of the Cascade, Washington, police department. He went to a hospital for an examination where he met Blair Sandburg, an anthropologist from Rainier University, whom Ellison initially mistook for a physician. Upon hearing Ellison's story, Sandburg declares that Ellison is a "Sentinel": in ancient tribes, Sentinels used their enhanced senses to protect their village. For Jim, Cascade is his village. Blair had been studying Sentinel mythology for years. While he found many individuals with one or two hyperactive senses, he had never before found a person with all five senses enhanced, a "true" Sentinel.
>
> Blair helps Jim control his senses and joins Jim as a police observer. Their unlikely partnership works, and together they fight crime in the streets of Cascade. The only person aside from Sandburg who knows Jim's secret is his captain and friend, Simon Banks.